# Is it bad to have classes as properties of all other classes?

Tags: design, design-patterns

I've been making MVC programs for work (I'm an intern) and I feel like I'm doing a pretty good job at abstraction, single responsibility, etc. But I have this feeling about how I keep making objects properties of other objects and I'm not sure if it's a bad thing.

Example:

```
User
{
     String Username;
     Int32 UserID;
          .
          .
          .
     BusinessLogicClass Variable;
}

BusinessLogicClass 
{
    AnotherClass Variable;
    AndAnother Variable2;
}

AnotherClass
{
     IThinkYoureGetting ThePoint;
}
```

All my Classes are properties of the others in one massive hierarchy, It's kind of what the business logic calls for but I can't help but wonder if I should be trying to prevent something like this. So I end up effectively with one variable that I control the children of, but the classes are separate.

Is this something common? Is it bad? If it is bad, what should I do about it?

Comment: You have already received an excellent answer and some comments. FYI, the technique you are using is generally referred to as [**Object composition or aggregation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition): _In programming languages, composite objects are usually expressed by means of references from one object to another; depending on the language, such references may be known as fields, members, properties or attributes, and the resulting composition as a structure, storage record, tuple, user-defined type (UDT), or composite type._ It is an important concept in OOP.

Comment: Another way of referring to this sort of approach is _indirection_ , although the term has a much broader meaning than just what you're doing here. Your concern about getting too deeply nested is reflected in a quote from [**Bjarne Stroustrup**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup) in the name of his mentor [**David J. Wheeler**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Wheeler_%28computer_scientist%29) : _All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection, except for the problem of too many layers of indirection._  Simply stated:You risk obfuscating your code.

Comment: "making MVC programs for work as an intern..." -- that seems very abstract. MVC is intended to make it easy to extend existing programs to add new views, etc. Hopefully your internship goes far enough to show you the benefits of MVC, and that you're actually making code that has some socio-economic value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is not necessarily bad. That is object-oriented programming: objects contain other objects. Each one is responsible for its own piece of the program, which often means encapsulating other objects.

For example, a car contains a transmission. That could be a complex class containing a bunch of other objects such as gears, clutch plates, etc. which could be abstracted as classes.

In an MVC framework, you should be careful to keep different concerns separate. For example, a view should not generally contain model objects: normally, the view communicates requested model updates through events, decoupling the two layers. But a view object could definitely contain other view objects, for example a panel containing buttons, text boxes, etc.

Business logic that pertains to program flow is strictly a concern for the Controller layer. Business logic that pertains to updating the model is a little more open to debate. In your example, it *may* be appropriate to put limited business logic in the User model, but only if that logic pertains to tasks such as validation, updating dependent fields, etc. in other words, tasks that are tightly coupled to the data contained in the User. It would *not* be appropriate for the User to contain logic that interacts with the UI or program flow.

Comment: Would you suppose something like my example would be bad? Where the user information object contains business logic object as the user is retrieving that information from the DB and I'm storing it there as an intermediate storage place so that I don't have to keep pulling it from the DB. I personally can see both how it would be an opinion to keep them separate and keep them together as the user is retrieving that information.

Comment: I updated my answer with more relevant details regarding the specific example in your question.

Comment: Okay, so my suspicion wasn't entirely incorrect. I should probably separate `User` and my `BusinessLogicClass` as suspected. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome. I would recommend reading up on MVC a bit more, you could start with Wikipedia or search on this site for questions on that topic. It is a **very** pervasive topic that will come up time and time again in a variety of software projects.

Comment: Would you recommend anything that gets to the conceptual stuff? I have the basics of the coding down I just need something more conceptual which is why any Google searches kind of deter me from reading them  as they're almost always the coding side.

Comment: The wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is ok but I would search through this site's MVC tag: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mvc and I recommend steering toward the more theoretical questions and not ones discussing specific implementations.

Comment: You are right to have your concerns - what you appear to be nervous of is what people call "tight coupling" - classes needing to be completely aware of other classes.  Once you have a handle on where you are today it might be worth looking up "dependency injection" and "inversion of control".  Techniques for ensuring that (in the right circumstances) the tangled web can be split into smaller, tighter and more appropriate webs.

Comment: @Rob That's a good point, I'm aware of coupling but I didn't really think of that as coupling for some odd reason. I have used dependency injection or at least a hybrid-like version of it anyways. I'll look into inversion of control. Thanks for the suggestions.